# Mask rasterio raster with geopandas shapefile

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, geopandas, rasterio

I am loading a shapefile using `geopandas` as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
StudyA = gpd.read_file('.../Study_Area_Polygon.shp')
```

Next, I am using `folium` to plot it interactively:

```
m = folium.Map([36.43, 43.06], zoom_start=12)
folium.GeoJson(StudyA).add_to(m)
m
```

My objective is now to use `rasterio` to mask a raster using the `shapefile` I have loaded before with the following code:

```
img, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(img, StudyA, crop=True, all_touched=True)
```

However, I am facing an issue as the information of the mask should be provided as a list of GeoJSON-like dicts according to `rasterio` documentation. How can I produce that `GeoJSON-like dicts` when reading the `shapefile` with geopandas.

Previously, I was reading the `shp` using the following code and it worked well. The issue is that I want/need to use `geopandas` for interactive plotting with `folium`

```
with fiona.open(".../Study_Area_Polygon.shp", "r") as StudyArea:
    shape = [feature["geometry"] for feature in StudyArea]
```

Comment: You can open it twice: once with Fiona to supply a mask, and one with GeoPandas for plotting with Folium.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the suggestion. However, I would like to avoid repetition and importing twice the same file. I would prefer to extract the `GeoJSON` information required by `rasterio` directly from the `geopandas` import

Answer (score 7):

If your geodataframe has a column named "geometry" and geometry consists of Shapely Polygons, the following works for me

```
from rasterio.mask import mask

out, _ = mask(data, gdf.geometry, invert=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a geodataframe (gdf), you can just pass the geometry values flattened to rasterio:

```
masked_raster, masked_raster_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(raster, gdf[['geometry']].values.flatten())
```

Comment: this is such a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in the future, I managed to make it work with the following code.

First, open an empty list. Then import the `shp` with `geopandas`. Next, we access the geometric information and extract it. The output of that is a `dict` containing the information required by `rasterio.mask.mask`

```
geom = []

StudyA = gpd.read_file('.../Study_Area_Polygon.shp')
coord = shapely.geometry.mapping(StudyA)["features"][0]["geometry"]
geom.append(coord)
```